# Unexpected result setting a shear matrix as transform

Tags: python, scripting, transforms, matrix

I am doing a visualization where I need to transform a sphere with a matrix. Easiest solution would be to just set the matrix as local transform but this gives me unexpected results.

I was trying around a little and found out, that setting `matrix_local`, `delta_...` and operating on vertex positions directly yields very different results. As an example, I tried it with a simple shear matrix. Here are the results:

Using matrix on vertex positions
[image: Using matrix on vertex positions]

Using local transformation matrix
[image: Using local matrix]

Using delta transform
[image]
This is the code:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import *

def transform_verts(context):
    obj = context.active_object
    mat = Matrix.Shear('XY', 4, (3,3))

    #this does what it is supposed to do
    for j in range(0, len(obj.data.vertices)):
        obj.data.vertices[j].co = mat @ obj.data.vertices[j].co

def transform_delta(context):
    obj = context.active_object

    # This does NOT work as intended :(
    # this deforms the sphere into an elongated Ellipsoide
    d_loc, d_rot, d_sc = Matrix.Shear('XY', 4, (3,3)).decompose()
    obj.delta_location = d_loc
    obj.delta_rotation_quaternion = d_rot
    obj.delta_scale = d_sc

def transform_matrix_local(context):
    obj = context.active_object

    # for unknown reasons it is not possible to do this with an object transformation matrix
    # setting matrix_local yields similar weird results as setting delta transform
    # I suppose it may have to do with Blender internally decomposing it
    obj.matrix_local = Matrix.Shear('XY', 4, (3,3))

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        #transform_verts(context)
        #transform_delta(context)
        transform_matrix_local(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator()
```

Why does setting the matrix_local also does something very different from what is intended? In my understanding, setting the matrix_local should do exactly the same as applying the matrix to vertex positions.

Is there a workaround for this issue that does not involve looping through vertices and setting the position manually? The above is just an example. My actual use case is a modal operator and right now I need to store the original vertex positions and loop through them each time `modal` is called. That is really slow compared to just setting the local transformation matrix.
If there isn't, any idea how to speed it up?

Edit: `obj.data.transform()` is not possible because I need to apply the matrix to the sphere each time. This matrix is not necessarily invertable, so I can't just do the inverse transformation from the previous call and then do the current transformation. I would only be able to use it if I can somehow restore the positions the vertices had before the transformation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`Mesh.transform`**

Can transform mesh directly by a matrix with `Mesh.transform(matrix)`  The matrix must be a 4x4.  Use in object mode. Update the mesh to see result.

Python console code, `C = bpy.context`

```
>>> mat = Matrix.Shear('XY', 4, (3,3))
>>> mat
Matrix(((1.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))

>>> C.object.data.transform(mat)
>>> C.object.data.update()
```

> But this is transforms the vertices for good. In the modal operator, I
>   need to apply it to the original positions of the sphere on each
>   update. And the matrix is not necessarily invertable, so I can't just
>   do the inverse beforehand, which makes it tricky

Shear matrix is not orthogonal, this is why it is not seen as an object matrix, and only in edit mode.

```
>>> mat.is_orthogonal
False
```

AFAIK will need to apply to verts to shear.

Some ways to copy mesh coords, swap out a mesh copy

```
>>> me = C.object.data
>>> me2 = C.object.data.copy()
>>> me2.transform(mat)
>>> C.object.data = me2 # see transform
>>> C.object.data = me # back to original
>>> bpy.data.meshes.remove(me2) # remove it when done
```

Foreach set and get

load the 3d vert coordinates into a ravelled array.  Have used numpy as the matrix algebra could be performed on it reshaped, although will find `Mesh.transform` is quick too.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.zeros(len(me.vertices) * 3)
>>> me.vertices.foreach_get("co", data)
>>> data
array([ 0.00000000e+00,  1.95090324e-01,  9.80785251e-01, ...,
        1.51397259e-08,  1.95089921e-01, -9.80785310e-01])
```

The data is ravelled, here it is reshaped to display the coordinates

```
>>> np.reshape(data, (-1, 3))
array([[ 0.00000000e+00,  1.95090324e-01,  9.80785251e-01],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  3.82683456e-01,  9.23879504e-01],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  5.55570245e-01,  8.31469595e-01],
       ...,
       [ 1.52975474e-07,  7.07106352e-01, -7.07106769e-01],
       [ 7.84696610e-08,  3.82682920e-01, -9.23879623e-01],
       [ 1.51397259e-08,  1.95089921e-01, -9.80785310e-01]])
```

Transform the data, update to see result

```
>>> me.transform(mat)
>>> me.update()
```

write back, update to see result.

```
>>> me.vertices.foreach_set("co", data)
>>> me.update()
```

Another OTT method would be to make a shape key and transform that.

Comment: But this is transforms the vertices for good. In the modal operator, I need to apply it to the original positions of the sphere on each update. And the matrix is not necessarily invertable, so I can't just do the inverse beforehand, which makes it tricky.

Comment: Copy the mesh on invoke? Or copy vert  coords with `foreach_get` and write with `foreach_set` or similarly with a `bmesh`   AFAIK shear is not applicable as an object matrix since the axes need to be orthogonal, hence  no shear available outside of edit mode.

Comment: I didn't know about `foreach_get` and `foreach_set`! Thanks for the hint. Do you how to use it with vectors? The documentation states "Only works for ‘basic type’ properties (bool, int and float)!"

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I already spend hours trying to wrap my head around this problem with the vertex transformation

Comment: Pleasure.  Thanks for updating Q on request.  Good question.

Answer (score 2):

I guess I'm too late to the party but there is still a bit hacky way to do it - won't affect the actual geometry and will allow you to add ANY possible transform to your project, even a shear transform.

In Blender there is a weird thing called [Parent Inverse Matrix](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/parent.html#parent-inverse) that's getting applied when you parent one object to another and don't use `Without Inverse` option. The way it's calculated it's basically just `object.parent.matrix_world.inverted()` at the moment when you added a parent - so it's kind of compensating the initial parent transform so child transform stays intact when you just created a relationship between objects. What is important is that how it is applied and stored. Taking those two parent matrices into account matrix_world for object is calculated like `obj.matrix_world = obj.parent.matrix_world @ (obj.matrix_parent_inverse @ obj.matrix_local)`.

There is annoyoing thing about `matrix_parent_inverse` that you cannot see it from the UI, you can access it only from python. Reason for that is that it can contain non-uniform transformations like a shear trasform that cannot be decomposed to location+rotation+scale. But this is the advantage we're going to use.

Basic object transform (and kind of delta transform too) is what I call decomposion safe matrix - meaning Blender keep it that way so that it can be safely decomposed and assembled back to the same matrix. Basically, `Matrix.LocRotScale(*matrix.decompose()) == matrix`. This is why it didn't worked for the author with `matrix_local` and `delta_location`/`delta_rotation`/`delta_scale`.

So, the solution I suggest is to store a shear in `matrix_parent_inverse`:

1. Create an empty object B that will be used only to make `matrix_parent_inverse` available.
2. Make B parent of A.
3. Set A.matrix_parent_inverse to shear transformation.
4. Voila.

Easy way to reproduce it is to run the code below in any Blender scene.

```py
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix

for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)

weird_transform = bpy.data.objects.new("Weird Transform", None)
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(weird_transform)

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
shear_cube = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
shear_cube.name = "Sheared Cube"

shear_cube.parent = weird_transform
shear_cube.matrix_parent_inverse = Matrix.Shear('XY', 4, (3,3))
```